# Do we embarrass someone in cheirem?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, nidui-ostracism

Let's suppose that someone in a community has been put in *cheirem*, for whatever reason. This would generally ban him from the community *shul*. Should this person show up in the community *shul*, however, what is the *halacha* in regards to forcing him to leave. Do we publicly embarrass this person, and make somewhat of a scene out of it, or is it better to simply completely ignore him (obviously with no *aliyot*, etc.)?

On the one hand, he isn't allowed where he is. On the other hand, embarrassing a person is likened to killing him or her.

Comment: He presumably knew what he was getting into by walking in. If he wants to embarrass himself that's his business.

Comment: Note that the Taz (YD 334:1) writes that we should withhold measures that would push a person away from Judaism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rama rules (YD 334:2) based on a responsum of Rivash (173) that one who is in cheirem is not banned from the community synagogue *qua* being in cheirem, though he does not count for the minyan. However, since one may not sit down within 4 amot of someone in cheirem (Shulchan Aruch ibid.), some communities do remove him (ֹגרשו) from the synagogue because of the hassles it causes to the community who want to sit down. From his language it seems that, in such a community, one would force him to leave against his will because of the trouble he causes the regular worshipers.

Comment: I think you use the word *qua* more than anyone else I have been exposed to.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman 3 times? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=qua+user%3A759

Comment: That doesn't include chat or comments.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman None in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=qua&user=28095&room=

Comment: Looks like you've only used it 5 times I can find: http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/query/114923/uses-of-the-word-qua

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I can find more: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/ numbers 36532 27220 33668 59227 49233 43253 and meta comment number 3322